# Is it possible to have a view in sql-server 2008 that splits one row into many?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

The back story is I am trying to write a view that takes a table who's every row is an ID and serialized data for that ID in a clob and presents it in sql navigable form. basically my code looks like:

```
CREATE VIEW UNSERIALIZED_TABLE_VIEW AS 
SELECT
    SOURCE_TABLE.ID SOURCE_ID,
    a.*
FROM
    SOURCE_TABLE,
    FUNCTION_WHICH_UNSERIALIZES((SELECT DATA FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE ID = SOURCE_ID)
```

I tried putting the function in the select statement, but that just gave a syntax error about it being undefined. When it runs the error is usually about a subquery returning too many values. I could just unserialize the data in batches, but now I'm really curious what's going wrong.

Example Data

```
@0History:23:ALPHANUMERICSTUFF1234567ID:11:ACCT1234567SourceMode:6:ANNUAL.ModeChanges:UniqueIndex:23:ALPHANUMERICSTUFF1234567ID:11:ACCT1234567OldValue:1:+NewValue:6:ANNUALChangeType:1:AChangeDate:20:6/03/2013 2:49:32 AM.
@0History:UniqueIndex:95:NOTTHESAME0987654|ALPHANUMERIC534|PRETEND349235|95CHARACTERSID:47:GNR44718500|PNR48CDQ704|PGP48090798|FGDS2345236SourceMode:26:ANNUAL|C-P-D|ANNUAL|ANNUALLoan:3:|||ModeChanges:UniqueIndex:95:00487SOMETHING4264500ORD|992581PROBABLY04ORD|0048SHOULD238BET|0095CHARS436PR638FGP07VDCID:47:GNR44718500|PNR48CDQ704|PGP48090798|FGDS2345236OldValue:7:+|+|+|+NewValue:26:ANNUAL|C-P-D|ANNUAL|ANNUALChangeType:7:A|A|A|AChangeDate:91:12/22/2013 11:53:11 PM|4/22/2013 11:53:11 PM|12/22/2013 11:53:11 PM|12/22/2013 11:53:11 PM.
```

The data is serialized table data of the form COLUMN_NAME:LENGTH_OF_ENTRY:DATA_FOR_COLUMN_ROW_1|DATA_FOR_COLUMN_ROW2|....NEXT_COLUMN_NAME...

Example of Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION_THAT_UNSERIALIZES (@clob varchar(max),@colname varchar(max)) RETURNS @NewValue TABLE (ID INT,value varchar(max)) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @colstart INT,@lenstart INT,@lenend INT,@collen VARCHAR(MAX),@lngth INT,@tmp VARCHAR(MAX), @rowid INT,@value VARCHAR(max),@next INT;
SELECT 
   @colstart = CHARINDEX(@colname,@tmp)+1,
   @lenstart = CHARINDEX(':',@tmp,@colstart)+1,
   @lenend   = CHARINDEX(':',@tmp,@lenstart),
   @collen   = SUBSTRING(@tmp,@lenstart,@lenend - @lenstart),
   @lngth    = CAST (@collen AS INT),
   @tmp      = SUBSTRING(@tmp,@lenend,@lngth);
WHILE LEN(@tmp) > 0 BEGIN
    SET @next = CHARINDEX('|',@tmp);
    IF @next > 0 BEGIN
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@tmp,0,@next);     
        SET @tmp   = SUBSTRING(@tmp,@next+1,LEN(@tmp) - @next);
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @value = @tmp;    
        SET @tmp   = '';
 END
 INSERT INTO @NewValue VALUES(@rowid,@value)
 SET @rowid = @rowid+1;
 END
 RETURN
```

Example Error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
```

The multi-part identifier "SOURCE_TABLE.SOURCE_ID" could not be bound.

.. I think there might have been another one, but can't figure out how to reproduce it right this minute.

Comment: Do you have example of the data?

Comment: Also, an example of the function, and the exact error you get when you run it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it was relevant. Adding now.

Comment: Do you realize that multi statement table valued functions are horrible for performance? What does this function do?

Comment: No, I had no idea that multi-statement-table-valued functions were horrible for performance, @SeanLange  thank you for pointing that out. The function takes two inputs, a line of data link the same data, and a column header. It parses the text and spits out a table with each individual value on its own row.

Comment: Converting this to an inline table valued function ( a single statement) would vastly help the performance. If you can post the whole function (including the declarations you left out) so I can run it locally I can help you turn that into an iTVF.

Comment: OK, added declarations. Show me what you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the syntax you need to accomplish what I think you are trying to do.

```
CREATE VIEW UNSERIALIZED_TABLE_VIEW AS 
SELECT
    SOURCE_TABLE.ID SOURCE_ID,
    a.*
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
CROSS APPLY FUNCTION_WHICH_UNSERIALIZES(DATA, @colname) a
```

I'm not certain what your @colname parameter should be; it is left out of your code in the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but I'm having issues because I need to call the function four times and it's giving me an 
    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 The multi-part identifier "SOURCE_TABLE.DATA" could not be bound. on the 2nd,3rd,and 4th instances.

 \@colname is short for "column name" and it's the text in the data that signifies where the entry for a particular column starts. eg an \@colname of 'StartDate' would correspond to the entries in the StartDate column of the serialized data.

Comment: I'm not sure, can you post the code where you're calling it four times?

Comment: various permutations of:
SELECT
    SOURCE_TABLE.ID SOURCE_ID,
    a.value,
    b.value,
    c.value,
    d.value
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
CROSS APPLY FUNCTION_WHICH_UNSERIALIZES(DATA, @colname1) a,
CROSS APPLY FUNCTION_WHICH_UNSERIALIZES(DATA, @colname2) b,
CROSS APPLY FUNCTION_WHICH_UNSERIALIZES(DATA, @colname3) c,
CROSS APPLY FUNCTION_WHICH_UNSERIALIZES(DATA, @colname4) d

 WHERE a.id =b.id AND b.id=c.id AND c.id = d.id

Comment: You shouldn't put the comma's between the cross apply statements.

Comment: Joins don't work either... it appears replacing the commas with "CROSS APPLY" does, though... yup, that did it.

Comment: yes, if you separate them with commas it is equivalent to specifying cross joins.  You need the cross apply in this case, so that the function call can gain access to the DATA field in SOURCE_TABLE for it's parameter.